# bitmap.compress(compressFormat.PNG,100,fout) compressing captured image and making it unreadable

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-camera

I'm currently making an app which allows the user to take an image and then save it to the devices memory. The act of taking the image and saving works fine, however my problem is that the image that is saved to memory is compressed and becomes unreadable.

Here is the snippet of code that once the image has been captured it saves it to the file location.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            // get bitmap
            pic = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(pic);

            String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/MyReceiptTracker";
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            File file = new File(dir,pic + ".png");

            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                pic.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();}
             catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Captured and Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 


        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: is it possible to save to a file without causing this compression that makes the file unreadable?. I understand that PNG is lossless so is there something in my code that is causing the image to become unreadable unreadable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have u resolved your issue still facing same issue image is not readable

Comment: Hi Erum. I did not solve this issue and but this project on hold for the moment because I could not figure out how to stop the compression.